# Qos d-link 3680

Tags: qos

So for ages I've wanted to limit the bandwidth of my sons pc. When he downloads it takes all the bandwidth and we can't even use netflix.

At the minute we are with sky fibre and the hub doesn't have qos.

So I've found an old d-link 3680, which I've bridged. So ethernet goes from the sky hub to the bridged d-link 3680 and another ethernet to his pc.

The d-link 3680 has qos but I don't understand what it's asking for? Here is a picture of what it's asking for…

[image: Qos rules image]

I've taken 2 photos and merged it together as 1. so you can see the options if I click either the priority or protocol tab

What do I input to limit his downloads? Source port range is greyed out I'm bot sure why? I don't even know what that means lol

Comment: You would have to input TCP/UDP on port 443 and port 80 to limit your son's Netflix usage. Even then, that likely won't result in what you want to achieve because it won't actually limit the bandwidth, only gives it a lower priority.  You need something like DD-WRT on the router to accomplish what you want.  There are routers with firmware that have more advanced QoS features. Your router isn't one of them.

Comment: I'd have a look at https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/bloat/wiki/What_can_I_do_about_Bufferbloat/ which has more tests & possible solutions than could possibly be précised here. As @Ramhound mentions, WRT is one of those solutions.